# Exporting all outlook emails into a pst file, generates a different file everytime. Why?

Tags: backup, microsoft-outlook-2007, export

I'm trying to export all of my emails into a backup file.
However, I wanna make sure it's correctly exported, by exporting 2 similar files. But everytime i do it, i make a checksum of the resulting pst file, and i notice it's different from the previous one. How can this happen if I didn't receive or sent any email meanwhile?

I just wanna make sure it's correctly exported, by exporting 2 similar files.

Comment: Why not make the PST export and then copy the PST file to create another file with the same one and then just rename it? You could then attach the PST files to your Outlook profile and browser thru to ensure all is there as expected. You could then check the checksum of both of those files to ensure those are the same but otherwise perhaps you have an issue with the file system it is being stored.

Comment: because that way it won't go trough the process of being created by outlook. I wanna make sure it's a similar file by the source, not just copy after it was created.. lol And that doesn't explain why the file is different everytime.

Comment: Checksum is usually based on file content I thought & not metadata attributes like date modified, etc. but I'm no checksum expert but trying to think without research on the topic for a quick pointer or two since I'm short on time right now. I thought if the original source content is what you are worried about (identical), then the export copy would be exactly what you need. I would think Outlook puts some other content part into the PST when it's created and thus the content can never be the same if the export start time is not identical. Export the folder only and see if that helps perhaps.